# Menu bar icon gone

Tags: xcode9, swift4.1

I'm absolutely new to Swift and trying to create simple menu bar app. When I add an icon to menu bar it's just flicking once and it's gone.

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application

        let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength:NSStatusItem.squareLength)
        if let button = statusItem.button {
            button.image = NSImage(named:NSImage.Name("StatusBarButtonImage"))
            //button.action = #selector(printQuote(_:))
        }
    }
```

There is an icon named StatusBarButtonImage in assets with "render as" set to "template image"

Answer (score 0):

Its because your `statusItem` is released after `applicationDidFinishLaunching`.